# Usage of "to" vs "onto" with verb "send"

Tags: prepositions

I just received a mail from someone about forwarding a document to a third person. I found this sentence:

```
...can you send it onto Amy for review?...
```

But I would write

```
...can you send it to Amy for review?...
```

Is correct the usage of **onto**?
Is there any difference in the meaning of both sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implied difference between sending it **to Amy** and sending it **on to Amy**.

This is an instance where you need to use two words **on to** instead of the single word **onto**.

**Onto Amy** would imply on top of Amy as in: **The dog jumped onto Amy**. But in your example the underlying phase concerned is **sending it on**, which means **forwarding it**

So the difference between **to** and **on to** in this case is that one indicates merely that the item is going to Amy and the other indicates that it is being forwarded to Amy via the recipient from the original source. That's to say, it involves three parties rather than two.

For more explanations and examples of the differences between **on to** and **onto**, see:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/onto

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825044652/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/onto-or-on-to)

Comment: To summarise in this case, **onto** is misused, **on to** implies forwarding or three parties and **to** is for the simple act of sending something. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right (Forwarding implies an original sender and an original recipient who sends the item on (**forwards it**) to an/other recipient/s.